# No suitable injection token for parameter 'functions' of class 'TodosComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, types

I am using 'firebase' instead of '@angular/fire' and got an error saying `No suitable injection token for parameter 'functions' of class 'TodosComponent'`.

Code written in **todos.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TodosService } from '../todos.service';
import { Todo } from './Todo';
import * as functions from 'firebase/functions';

declare var StripeCheckout: StripeCheckoutStatic;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todos',
  templateUrl: './todos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todos.component.scss']
})
export class TodosComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  todos!: Todo[];
  localItem: string | null;
  completedTodos: number = 0;
  date: string = new Date().toUTCString();

  constructor(private functions: functions.Functions) {
      ..........
  }

  ......

}
```

I am having a problem in `private functions: functions.Functions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you imported directly from 'firebase/functions', you don't need to inject in the constructor.

You can directly use the *functions*.

Remove `private functions: functions.Functions` from constructor.

Use the *functions* directly. No need to use *this.functions*

for example,

```
functions.firestore.document('/messages/{documentId}')
```